# Cannot verify PGP signature for veracrypt executable

Tags: windows, gnupg, pgp, gpg-signature, veracrypt

I just downloaded a fresh copy of veracrypt from the official website, however I'm having some trouble verifying its signature.

Here's what I did:

1. gpg import veracrypt.asc (from [here](https://www.idrix.fr/VeraCrypt/VeraCrypt_PGP_public_key.asc))
2. -gpg --verify "VeraCrypt Setup 1.24-Update7.exe.sig" "VeraCrypt Setup 1.24-Update7.exe"

PGP for some reason is unable to verify the signature, what gives?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd provide GPG output it would be easier to answer.
However, most likely the reason is in redundant parameter, your command line should be like:

`gpg --verify "VeraCrypt Setup 1.24-Update7.exe.sig"`, given that both .sig and .exe files are put in the same directory.

This is called 'detached signature': `.exe.sig` file contains signature itself, and GnuPG would look for the signed contents in a file without `.sig` extension.